# MySQL union and sum two table

Tags: mysql, sum, union-all

I need a solution for display same day records and show SUM of each column, so far I have a query to show union records like:

```
SELECT 
    datetime, 
    remarks, 
    void, 
    invoice, 
    reload, 
    redeem 
FROM
    (
      SELECT datetime, remarks, '' void, '' invoice, points_intake reload, '' redeem, 1 ord
      FROM bpp_intake_logs
      WHERE outlet = 'KUL' AND DATE(datetime) = '2017-06-13'
      UNION ALL

      SELECT datetime, remarks, void, invoice, '', points_consume, 2
      FROM bpp_consume_logs
      WHERE outlet = 'KUL' AND DATE(datetime) = '2017-06-13' 
    ) q
ORDER BY datetime DESC, ord
```

and the result table is show like:

```
datetime            | remarks                        | void | invoice  | reload | redeem |
2017-06-13 15:53:31 | Point restored - void XY203460 |      |          | 10     |        |
2017-06-13 15:37:27 | reload / top-up credit         |      |          | 10     |        |
2017-06-13 15:35:56 | redeem from VIP card           |  1   | XY203460 |        | 10     |
2017-06-13 15:16:03 | redeem from VIP card           |      | XY203456 |        | 5      |
```

Now, I wanted to add a cell to sum each `reload` and `redeem` at the bottom of its belonging column, like:

```
datetime            | remarks                        | void | invoice  | reload | redeem |
2017-06-13 15:53:31 | Point restored - void XY203460 |      |          | 10     |        |
2017-06-13 15:37:27 | reload / top-up credit         |      |          | 10     |        |
2017-06-13 15:35:56 | redeem from VIP card           |  1   | XY203460 |        | 10     |
2017-06-13 15:16:03 | redeem from VIP card           |      | XY203456 |        | 5      |
                                                                       | 20     | 15     |
```

As seen, SUM **20** and **15** are allocated at the bottom cell.

Is that possible to get a results in this way?

Comment: You can not do this in one single query. But you can calculate total value of reload and redeem using programming language like php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what youre looking for????

```
SELECT 
datetime, 
remarks, 
void, 
invoice, 
SUM(reload), 
SUM(redeem) 
FROM
(
  SELECT datetime, remarks, '' void, '' invoice, points_intake reload, '' redeem, 1 ord
  FROM bpp_intake_logs
  WHERE outlet = 'KUL' AND DATE(datetime) = '2017-06-13'
  UNION ALL

  SELECT datetime, remarks, void, invoice, '', points_consume, 2
  FROM bpp_consume_logs
  WHERE outlet = 'KUL' AND DATE(datetime) = '2017-06-13' 
) q
GROUP BY datetime desc, remarks asc, void asc, invoice asc with rollup

ORDER BY datetime DESC, ord
```

Comment: for understanding rollup, please refer ::: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)